# Perl: Separate the MSB and rest of the bits from a hex

Tags: perl

I need to separate the MSB and the rest of the bits from a hex string. So for example: I have a hex string `a2`, which is equivalent to `1010 0010`. I want to separate out the MSB (1 in this case), and rest of the number convert to decimal. I think I can do something like this:

```
$hex = 'a2';
$dec = hex($hex);
$bin = sprintf("%b", $dec);
$msb = substr $bin, 0, 1;
$rest = substr $bin 1, 7;

$restDec = oct("0b" . $rest);
```

However, I do not like using strings for bit operations. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trivial using bitwise operators:

```
$msb  = ($dec & 128) >> 7
$rest = ($dec & 127)
```

Explanation:

Decimal 128 is `0x80` or `0b1000_0000`, so using the bitwise "and" operator with 128 masks (sets to zero) all but the top bit, which we then shift down to the LSB where the result ends up being 0 or 1.  In actuality you could dispense with the masking operation and just shift right but explicitly masking has two advantages:

1. It makes the intent crystal clear, and
2. works even if you inadvertently apply this to a number larger than 255.

Decimal 127 is `0x7F` or `0b0111_1111` and bitwise "and-ing" this with `$dec` sets the MSB to zero while leaving alone the rest of the bits.

Additional note: Perl has hexadecimal numeric literals (`0x...`) *and* binary literals (`0b...`), so the above could also be written

```
$msb  = ($dec & 0x80) >> 7
$rest = ($dec & 0x7F)
```

Or even

```
$msb  = ($dec & 0b10000000) >> 7
$rest = ($dec & 0b01111111)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was just going to ask for it.